# How to get business partner for KTP (innovate UK) application?

Tags: funding, united-kingdom

I want to know how to get KTP grants. I understand that I need business partner to apply. how to get business partner?
I have read the guidelines for application that it should be with business partner. I do not know how to get business partner to do the work with me.

Comment: Can you provide some more information and context?  What field are you working in?  What is your position?  Have you contacted the relevant office at your university to ask for guidance?  Have you got in touch with other people in your field and similar post to ask how they managed it?  Do you already have an idea for what type of business could benefit from your particular expertise?

Comment: This is a question about a specific research funding stream in the UK, and strategies for going about applying for and securing funding from this stream would certainly be interesting to many UK early career academics (including myself), so I think it would be on-topic. But I do agree with @FelixU that a lot of context is missing for this to be a well-posed question, especially since not all of the people on this platform are working in UK academia. Might have a stab of improving it in a few hours (if this would be on topic), but can't currently.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, KTP projects are initiated by the business partner, who have a specific need/project in mind that would benefit their company. They then seek a relevant academic partner and apply for KTP funding together.

I'm not sure if you're speaking as an individual or a prospective academic partner. If you're speaking as an individual, you'd expect to just apply for an existing KTP role as advertised on the Innovate UK website/ job search sites.

If you're from a prospective academic partner (i.e. university) with a specific project that would benefit a business in your area of research, do your research into relevant companies, speak to them, and you may find a willing business partner to initiate a KTP bid with.